# Can we apply check on the property field of json schema?

Tags: python, json

I want to validate my json.

If the **is_dummy** field exists and is set to `False` the fields **username** and **password** are required, if it is set to `True` they are not.

But it is also valid if **is_dummy** is not present.

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {"type": "string", "minLength": 1},
        "username": {"type": "string", "minLength": 1},
        "password": {"type": "string", "minLength": 1},
        "is_dummy": {"type": "boolean"},
    },
    "if": {"properties": {"is_dummy": {"const": False}}},
    "then": {"required": ["username", "password"]}
}
```

Comment: Read JSON file, You can check particular field, you can check any value of field same like using python dict.

Comment: Wrong dict/json input

Answer (score 1):

You can check if `is_dummy` is in your json with :

```
if 'is_dummy' in data['properties'].keys():
    # Do you want
```

To check if the value is `False` you can use :

```
if data['properties']['is_dummy'] == False:
    # Do what you want
```

You can use the same logic to check your username/password fields